# .htaccess issues HTTP redirect if query matches directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite to send queries to PHP for handling in a CMS. My problem: if the query is the name of a directory, the query that gets sent to PHP is added to the URL.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /process.php\?query=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

So if the user types in

```
http://example.com/lolcats
```

mod_rewrite silently redirects to

```
http://example.com/process.php?query=lolcats
```

which is great. But if `lolcats` is a directory, mod_rewrite redirects (NOT silently) to

```
http://example.com/lolcats/?query=lolcats
```

adding the query to the end of the original request. Apache still serves the PHP output, but it changes the URL in the user's address bar.

So I need to stop the query from being added to the request even if the query is the name of a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `DirectorySlash` issue, where apache redirects with a trailing slash when you try to access a directory.

You can either turn `DirectorySlash Off` (noting that there is [a security warning concerning turning this off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)), or try to have mod_rewrite handle it preemptively with something like:

```
# Above your existing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# and small modification to your existing rule to handle trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /process.php\?query=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

THough if you are routing all existing directories through `process.php`, the security warning can probably be ignored.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the second option, since I wanted trailing slashes to be added by default. I made a small change to the slash rewrite (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution offered by Jon Lin above, with a slight modification to the rule that adds a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

This makes the rule work for addresses that have multiple slashes in them, such as

```
http://example.com/path/to/page
```

The main rewrite to PHP is exactly as Jon indicated:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /process.php\?query=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```